# JavaScript return an anonymous function inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Why `getNameFun` has an anonymous function returned (see segment1), can it just return `this.name`(see segment2)?

**Segment1:**

```
var name = "The Window";
　　var object = {
　　　　name : "My Object",
　　　　getNameFunc : function(){
　　　　　　return function(){
　　　　　　　　return this.name;
　　　　　　};
　　　　}
　　};
　　alert(object.getNameFunc()());
```

**Segment2:**

```
var name = "The Window";
　　var object = {
　　　　name : "My Object",
　　　　getNameFunc : function(){
　　　　　　
　　　　　　　　return this.name; // different is here!
　　　　　　
　　　　}
　　};
　　alert(object.getNameFunc());
```

Comment: Where did this code come from? Which part are you having problems with specifically?

Comment: "this" isn't always what you think it is

Comment: In your segment 2 issue, remove extra function ()() to () also "this" isn't always what you think it is... see my answer

Comment: can you explain why in this case  "this" isn't what you think it is?

Comment: "this" is the invoker, sometimes its the "window" sometimes it could be a control (textbox, etc...), all depends on how the code was invoked. I posted the way I would do it in my edited answer. More OO approach.

Comment: hmm, but why in `segment2` this is not always what I think? whats the trick? shouldn't `this`  always refers to `object` that contains the `getNameFunc` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
 var myclass = function(){
     var self = this;
     self.Name = "My Object";

    self.getNameFunc = function(){ return self.Name;}
}

var myc = new myclass();
alert(myc.getNameFunc());
```

Here is a fiddle to help

http://jsfiddle.net/AqdQG/

Comment: I still don't understand, why `var self = this` is needed? var myclass = function(){
     
     this.Name = "My Object";
    
     this.getNameFunc = function(){ return this.Name;}
     
} such way works fine.

Comment: This article will explain it better, bottom line that is "this" has special meaning in JS, and it is not like other languages (C#, VB etc...) http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations